# 1.#QNANO in output in C language?

Tags: c, pointers, return, output, function-calls

```
#include <stdio.h>

float diff_abs(float,float);

int main() {
  float x;
  float y;
  scanf("%f", &x);
  scanf("%f", &y);
  printf("%f\n", diff_abs(x,y));
  return 0;
}

float diff_abs(float a, float b) {
  float *pa = &a;
  float *pb = &b;
  float tmp = a;
  a = a-b;
  b = *pb-tmp;
  printf("%.2f\n", a);
  printf("%.2f\n", b);
}
```

Hello guys, i'm doing a C program which should keep in a variable a-b, and in b variable b-a.
It's all ok, but if i run my code at the end of output, compiler shows me this message:

```
3.14
-2.71
5.85
-5.85
1.#QNAN0
```

what does means 1.#QNANO?

Comment: p.s. 3.14 and -2.71 is the input, 5.85 and -5.85 are input and output

Comment: Nothing of that outout is from the compiler. And your code invokes undefined behaviour. Why do you igonre compiler warnings? The code also shows other missconceptions. C is strictly pass-by-value!

Comment: You don't have a return in the function.

Comment: Did you google for `1.#QNAN` first? [1.#QNAN error C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4617796/995714), and it's `QNAN0`, not `QNANO` [1.#QNAN0 output when calculating standard deviation C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29210975/995714)

Comment: I reopened the question as it was marked to a [wrong dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276434/could-someone-explain-what-does-1-qnan-mean).

Comment: Yeah, i know, today i began to study pointers and vectors, so i'm new in this type of programming

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc While the links are all useful, in this particular case, the UB is the reason behind the output and hence, cannot be justified anyway. :) Just sayin'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a function returns no value, with a valid return type, is it okay to for the compiler to throw garbage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936011/if-a-function-returns-no-value-with-a-valid-return-type-is-it-okay-to-for-the)

Comment: [Could someone explain what does “-1.#QNAN” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8276434/995714)

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes I overlooked the last question and forgot about the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece of code `printf("%f\n", diff_abs(x,y))` you are telling the compiler to print a `float` type of variable which should be the return value of the function `diff_abs`. But in your function `diff_abs` you are not returning any value.

So `%f` which is waiting for a `float`, will not get any value and it will print `#QNAN0` which means `Not A Number`. So you can change your code as follows:

**In your main:**

```
//printf("%f\n", diff_abs(x,y));   //comment this line
diff_abs(x,y);  //just call the function
```

**In the function:**

```
void diff_abs(float a, float b) {  //change the return value to void
  //float *pa = &a;   //you are not using this variable
  float *pb = &b;
  float tmp = a;
  a = a-b;
  b = *pb-tmp;
  printf("%.2f\n", a);
  printf("%.2f\n", b);
  return;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. @FulvioDenza

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you don't `return` a value from the called function `diff_abs()` and you're trying to use the `return`-ed value. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.1, *Function definitions*

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Based on your comments, it appears, you are not needed to have any return value from the function. In that case,

- Change the function signature to return type `void`
- Just call the function, get rid of the last `printf()` call in `main()` altogether. The `printf()`s inside the called function will get executed and the prints will appear on their own, you don't need to pass the function as an argument to another `printf()` for that.

Comment: i tried lot of way, for example i put at the end of the function a return 0, return a && b, and so on, but anyway the terminal don't show me just 5.85 and -5.85

Comment: @FulvioDenza change `printf("%f\n", diff_abs(x,y));` to `diff_abs(x,y);`, i guess that's what you need.